# how to authenticate login in mvc using sqldatabase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. I have given a task in which i want to  authenticate login in in mvc using database.
2. I have a Role table and another table user table.
3. I want to display first a login page and if he is a admin then he have a all rights and if he is user then he have limited rights.

Comment: What you did so far ? There are sample projects for this kind of needs on the web...

Comment: i tired a lot.s of tutorial...but wont help it...

Comment: specifically what tutorial(s) did you try, and what didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete solution to authentication, authorization and identity related issues for ASP.NET MVC web applications is **Identity 2**.

It is probably an overkill in your case since you need just a simple authentication and authorization but I strongly suggest to start learning Identity 2 as soon as possible because it will give you a great advantage in more complex scenarios (login from social, 2 factor authentication, claims etc.).

Check this [article](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx) and following ones: in my opinion those are the best way to learn Identity 2.

It can be difficult to understand and you will need more than 10 minutes but believe me: it's a great investment!

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

- I have given a task in which I want to authenticate login in mvc using database
- I have a `Role` table and a `User` table
- I want to display first a login page and if he is a admin then he have a all rights and if he is user then he have limited rights

Here is the solution. I add a login view in user controller and declare session for admin and user.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
 {
        var query = db.Users.Where(q => q.UserName == user.UserName && q.Password == user.Password);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["uname"] = user.UserName; 

            if (query.Any())
            {
                if (query.FirstOrDefault().Role.Role1.ToLower() == "admin")
                {
                    Session["admin"] = true; //define admin session here
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "user");
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["uname"] = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "user", new { id = query.FirstOrDefault().Id });
                }
            }
        }

        return View(user);
}
```

And if someone logs in as **user** then he can see his own details and edit it. And if someone logs in as **admin** then he can see all users details and have full authority.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     var users = db.Users.ToList();
     var session = Session["uname"]; 

     if (Session["admin"] == null) //if admin is null
     {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User"); //admin redirected at login page
     }
     else if (Session["admin"] != null) //if admin is not null and its set to admin then 
     {
            return View(users.ToList()); //he can see private data
     }
     else
     {
           //if user is login and he tried to redirected page to user
           //information 
           //for eg:user/details/2
           //then he tried to access private data then
           //for eg :user
           //then this following url will restrict the user
           //andredirect to Logout Page
           return RedirectToAction("About", "Home"); 
     }
}
```